# how to write a link in python in two different lines?

Tags: python, web

I have the following code that i want to write the links in two different lines but i can't use the triple quotation (""") and i want a valid way to do that :

toy_story data

```
toy_story = media.Movie("Toy Story",
                    "A story of a boy an his toy that come to life",
                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg",
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYz2wyBy3kc")
```

avatar data

```
avatar = media.Movie("Avatar",
                 "A marine on an alien planet",
                 "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b0/Avatar-Teaser-Poster.jpg",
                 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PSNL1qE6VY")
```

Comment: some one suggested using "# noqa" but i don't know how to use it or what is it .

Comment: what is "toy_story"? a parameter ? what do you mean - write in to lines ? please explain what you've already done

Comment: all i want to do is just separate the link in two lines cause the maximum characters i'm allowed to write in one line is 79 according to the pep8 rules and it's not recommended to use the triple quotation """ with links so i'm trying to find another way

Comment: please add a part of code of how've tried to solve it ? is it GUI ?

Comment: """https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b0/



Avatar-Teaser-Poster.jpg"""

Comment: that link i want to write it in two lines with out using the triple """

Comment: is it  a GUI ? you didnt answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
avatar = media.Movie(
    "Avatar",
    "A marine on an alien planet",
    (
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org"
        "/wikipedia/en/b/b0/Avatar-Teaser-Poster.jpg"
    ),
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PSNL1qE6VY",
)
```

It uses the fact that python treats `("foo" "bar"   "baz")` as equivalent and equal to `"foobarbaz"`.

Comment: do you know if that way is recommended in the pep8 rules or not ? 
i tried it and it worked but i should follow the pep8 rules in this project

Comment: You should try running `pep8` (or better yet, `flake8`) on your code, then you will know! `pip install flake8` and then just run `flake8` where your code lives.

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer if it does indeed answer your question :)